# Facebook Marketing API - CTA on promoted post

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

So I want to create new adcreative on Facebook using a page post as object_story_id for the creative spec. But I can't seem to append "call_to_action_type" parameter in conjunction with object_story_id. Is there other way to do this? Boosting a post natively in Facebook allows to add CTA to a post.